# Merge 2 dataframes with values separated by commas in one of the dataframes

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes like this

```
df1 <- data.frame(Colors = c("Yellow","Pink","Green","Blue","White","Red"
                            ,"Cyan","Brown","Violet","Orange","Gray"))

df2 <- data.frame(Colors = c("Yellow,Pink","Green","Gold","White","Red,Cyan,Brown",
                             "Violet","Magenta","Gray"))
```

I am trying to merge these 2 dataframes and return rows in df2, which are also present in df1. I also need to make sure the

My **desired output** is

```
          Colors
     Yellow,Pink
           Green
           White
  Red,Cyan,Brown
          Violet
            Gray
```

If I do     `df <- inner_join(df2,df1)`, 
then i don't get the rows `Yellow,Pink` & `Red,Cyan,Brown`

What am I missing here? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "Yellow,Pink" is not the same as "Yellow","Pink", so that would not be returned.

Comment: Same for Red, Cyan, Brown.  Essentially you're trying to join on two different strings in those two locations.  Joins operate by matching up ids that are exactly the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base `R` solution using `pmatch` on each split item:

```
split_list <- strsplit(as.character(df2$Colors),",")
keep_lgl   <- sapply(split_list,function(x) !anyNA(pmatch(x,df1$Colors)))
df2[keep_lgl,,drop=FALSE]

#           Colors
# 1    Yellow,Pink
# 2          Green
# 4          White
# 5 Red,Cyan,Brown
# 6         Violet
# 8           Gray
```

Note: I match a sequence of colors only if all colors are available in `df1`.

Some `tidyverse` approaches:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% mutate(keep=Colors) %>%
  separate_rows(Colors) %>%
  add_count(keep) %>%
  inner_join(df1) %>%
  add_count(keep) %>% # doesn't do anything here but important in general
  filter(n==nn)   %>% # same
  distinct(keep)  %>%
  rename(Colors=keep)

# # A tibble: 6 x 1
# Colors
# <fctr>
# 1    Yellow,Pink
# 2          Green
# 3          White
# 4 Red,Cyan,Brown
# 5         Violet
# 6           Gray

df2 %>% mutate(keep=Colors) %>%
  separate_rows(Colors) %>%
  left_join(df1 %>% mutate(Colors2=Colors,.)) %>%
  group_by(keep) %>%
  summarize(filt=anyNA(Colors2)) %>%
  filter(!filt) %>%
  select(-2)

# # A tibble: 6 x 1
#             keep
#           <fctr>
# 1           Gray
# 2          Green
# 3 Red,Cyan,Brown
# 4         Violet
# 5          White
# 6    Yellow,Pink
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex_inner_join` from `fuzzyjoin` package to join `df1` and `df2`. Finally, select the unique rows from `df2` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

regex_inner_join(df2, df1, by=c(Colors = "Colors")) %>%
  select(Colors = Colors.x) %>% distinct()

#           Colors
# 1    Yellow,Pink
# 2          Green
# 3          White
# 4 Red,Cyan,Brown
# 5         Violet
# 6           Gray

# Just to demonstrate, result of joined tables using regex_inner_join. One,
# can work-out to convert data in desired format afterwards.

regex_inner_join(df2, df1, by=c(Colors = "Colors")) 
#         Colors.x Colors.y
# 1    Yellow,Pink   Yellow
# 2    Yellow,Pink     Pink
# 3          Green    Green
# 4          White    White
# 5 Red,Cyan,Brown      Red
# 6 Red,Cyan,Brown     Cyan
# 7 Red,Cyan,Brown    Brown
# 8         Violet   Violet
# 9           Gray     Gray
```